# jQuery DataTables: Plain array or Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

using jQuery and its plugins DataTables, finding a little abnormal behavior; if I have an object as a result, it works quietly; if I have a plain array, however, appears the phrase: "No data available in table".

I found the solution to display the contents of a plain array:

```
"ajax": {
  "url": "./pages/tabledata.php",
  "dataSrc": ""
}
```

but of course in the case of the subject, the script does not work and gives me back the phrase given above.

My question is:

you can change the code attached to check if an object is or if it is a plain array?

Thanks in advance

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 if ($('#mytable').length) {

    $('#mytable').dataTable({
      "ajax": "./pages/tabledata.php",
      "columns": [
        {"data": "id", "visible": false, "searchable": false},
        {"data": "code"},
        {"data": "name"}
      ],
      "order": [ 1, 'asc']
    })
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="mytable" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Code of Data</th>
      <th>Name User</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

JSON for object:

```
{
    "data":[
        {
            "id":"1",
            "code":"PRF00001",
            "name":"Test 1"
        },{
            "id":"2",
            "code":"PRF00002",
            "name":"Test 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON for plain array:

```
{
    "data":{
        "id":"1",
        "code":"PRFS00001",
        "name":"Test 1"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that datatables don't recognize the "data" from the plain array format as a array, so there's nothing to list since its a object.

but if u change the format to this:

```
{
  "data": [ //<=
    {
      "id":"1",
      "code":"PRFS00001",
      "name":"Test 1"
    }
  ] //<=
}
```

then you will see the data appears again.

i made a fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/9chxhmk2/

here's a reference to the recognized json format for datatables: http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/post.html

Comment: Thanks kabstergo, your help is always precious!